# Can't add strings containing currencies

Tags: java, android

I have two errors in my code that I don't know how to solve it.

Please show them and tell me what to do.

[image]

[image]

Here are the codes of my app:

```
public class Food {

String price = null;
String name = null;
boolean selected = false;

public Food(String price, String name, boolean selected) {
    super();
    this.price = price;
    this.name = name;
    this.selected = selected;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Generate list View from ArrayList
        displayListView();
        checkButtonClick();
    }

    private void displayListView() {

        //Array list of foods
        ArrayList<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<Food>();
        Food food = new Food("15 SAR", "Chicken Meal", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("10 SAR", "Sliced Chicken", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("20 SAR", "Sandwich Chicken", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("10 SAR", "Hot Chicken", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("6 SAR", "Grilled potatoes", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("2 SAR", "Pepsi", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("17 SAR", "Fish Meal", false);
        foodList.add(food);

        //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
                R.layout.food_info, foodList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {

        private ArrayList<Food> foodList;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                               ArrayList<Food> foodList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, foodList);
            this.foodList = new ArrayList<Food>();
            this.foodList.addAll(foodList);

        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView price;
            CheckBox name;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.food_info, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
                holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Food food = foodList.get(position);
            holder.price.setText(" (" + food.getPrice() + ")");
            holder.name.setText(food.getName());
            holder.name.setChecked(food.isSelected());

            holder.name.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    food.setSelected(b);
                }
            });
            holder.name.setTag(food);

            return convertView;

        }

    }

    private void checkButtonClick() {

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setContentView(R.layout.invoic_page);
                int totalPrice = 0;
                for (Food f : foodList) {
                    if (f.isSelected) {
                        totalPrice += f.getPrice();
                    }

                    //totalPrice variable now has the total of all selected items
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

I tried to solve them as I can but other errors appear in different places of the code so I want the best solution.

Comment: In first Image, make variable final and in second, use Integer.parseInt(yourstring);

Comment: Put your blinking-text-cursor over your error and press ALT+ENTER -> ENTER

Comment: Is this a multicurrency system? If not there is no need to use strings for prices and repeat the currency in each string.

Comment: Agree with @weston, I think you want to change the type of `price` and `getPrice()` to int. It will solve problem no. 2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`totalPrice` is `int` and in `Food` model class `price` is `String`. So you need convet

```
for (Food f : foodList) {
            if (f.isSelected) {
                totalPrice += Integer.parseInt(f.getPrice());
            }

            //totalPrice variable now has the total of all selected items
        }
```

and `final Food food = foodList.get(position);` need to define final

Comment: Did you see what was in the prices?

Answer (score 0):

The second issue of money as `String`s. You can't simply add `"1 SAR"` and `"2 SAR"` and expect to get `"3 SAR"`.

If this is a single currency system, don't append `" SAR"` everywhere and don't use strings to store the values, either `int`s or `long`s and store your currency's lowest division, e.g. halalas.

`new Food("15 SAR", "Chicken Meal", false);` becomes `new Food(1500, "Chicken Meal", false);`

Then to display to the user a price:

```
String forDisplay = String.format("%.2f SAR", totalHalas/100);
```

Alternatively, especially if this is a multicurrency system create a class for your currency:

Personally I would use a library for this: [Joda Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/).

But you can also roll your own:

```
public class Money {
   private final String currency;
   private final long value;
   private final int dp;

   public Money(long value, int dp, String currency){
       this.value = value;
       this.dp = dp;
       this.currency = currency;
   }

   //optional helper factory method
   public static Money sar(long halas){
       return new Money(halas, 2, "SAR");
   }

   public Money add(Money other){
       if(!other.currency.equals(currency))
           throw new RuntimeException("Can't add different currencies");
       if(!other.dp.equals(dp))
           throw new RuntimeException("The decimal places do not match");
       return new Money(value + other.value, dp, currency);
   }

   public String toString(){
       return String.format("%."+dp+"f %s", value/Math.pow(10,dp), currency);
   }
}
```

Example usage:

```
System.out.println(new Money(1500,2,"SAR").add(new Money(623,2,"SAR")));
//or:
System.out.println(Money.sar(1500).add(Money.sar(623)));
```

[Outputs](http://ideone.com/LWGALe):

```
21.23 SAR
```

Answer (score -1):

For the first error, you need need to make the `food` variable final:

```
// Make this final.
final Food food = foodList.get(position);
holder.name.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
          food.setSelected(b);
        }
 });
```

For the second error, you need to convert the String value to interger:

```
for (Food f : foodList) {
  if (f.isSelected) {
    totalPrice += Integer.valueOf(f.getPrice());
  }
}
```

But you better make the `price` variable as integer or [BigInteger](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger.html) for price in **Food** class or [BigDecimal](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

---

**UPDATE**

**Never** save your currency in your price value. Instead, you can add a new variable like currency name. Do not save it for the sake of portability and future bug-free code.

Comment: Did you see what was in the prices currently?

Comment: Amazing the errors gone :) ... but I still can't resolve symbols foodList and isSelected here: for (Food f : foodList) { if (f.isSelected) {

Comment: Have you run it though?

Comment: @weston: Thank you for telling me. I don't change the answer. Just add a description about real-world usage.

Comment: @Sahora: As my updated answer, you need to separate price and the currency. My answer will work but the price value will be trimmed.

Comment: Yeah weston I ran it and gave me three error messages.. Error:(129, 31) error: cannot find symbol variable foodList ... Error:(130, 26) error: cannot find symbol variable isSelected ... Error:(130, 24) error: illegal start of type.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I'll do now :-) You really helped me.